# GET JSON from controller to view ( can't convert LIST[Model.object] into JSon in JS

Tags: playframework-2.2

Can someone told me how to convert or simply get Json from controller into View ?
I tried to convert List to Json in my JS(View) but no way!! 
My purpose is to get in my view data coming from controller then display my JQUERY CHART, here is my example:

**1- CHART simple HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
            title: {
                text: "Line Chart"
            },
            axisX: {
                interval: 10
            },
            data: 

            [{
                type: "line",

                dataPoints: 
                [
                  { x: 10, y: 45 },
                  { x: 20, y: 14 },
                  { x: 30, y: 20 },
                  { x: 40, y: 60 },
                  { x: 50, y: 50 },
                  { x: 60, y: 80 },
                  { x: 70, y: 40 },
                  { x: 80, y: 60 },
                  { x: 90, y: 10 },
                  { x: 100, y: 50 },
                  { x: 110, y: 40 },
                  { x: 120, y: 14 },
                  { x: 130, y: 70 },
                  { x: 140, y: 40 },
                  { x: 150, y: 90 },
                ]
            }]
        });
        chart.render();
    }
    </script>
    <script src="../../canvasjs.min.js"></script>
    <title>CanvasJS Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chartContainer" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

**2- Controller :**

```
public Result graph1() 
{
    List<Computer> userC = Computer.find.all();

    return ok( views.html.graphs.chart1.render(User.findByEmail(request().username()) , userC ) );
}
```

**3- My View : (Data will come from 1-database >> 2-controller List >> 3- display View with (chart) **

```
@(user: User, listComputers: List[Computer])
@import play.api.libs.json.Json

@scripts = { 




<script type="text/javascript">

function myFunction() 
{


@********This is what i tried**********
@Html(Json.toJson(listComputers))

console.log(JSON.stringify(jsArr));
*************************************@
}

</script>



           }


@main(user, scripts) {

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

}
```

Comment: The result of `Json.toJson` is never assigned to a variable called `jsArr`, so I'm not sure what you expect to show up in that console call.

Comment: This was on of my tries, even with affecting jsArr to the variable it is not working !!
what could be the best way to fill datapoints from controller ? thank you so much
tried those link and noone works :
1-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25262308/how-to-get-json-into-a-js-variable-out-of-a-scala-json-string
2-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565485/post-json-data-from-playframework-form
3-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352310/present-json-data-to-a-play-framework-template

Comment: Did you check what this code produces? Because `Json.toJson` produces an `ObjectNode` instance and I'm guessing it will put an object reference in the view. Try to `stringify` the outcome of the `toJson` call.

Comment: Im a fool girl, it was really simple :
juste changed this : 
      { x: 10, y: 45 },
by this :
    @for(c <- listComputers) {           
    {x: @c.id, y:@c.id },
                             }

thank you anyway :) if you have another kind of solutions let me know ;)

I do not know if by asking the question on stackoverflow I could see that the solution is very simple, in any case I thank you very much